# Google Endpoints generated libraries for JAVA have wrong package

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have strange problem with generating process. After click on `Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library` everything works right, but if I look in the `endpoint-libs/` folder I saw that former folder structure was changed.

First part of it is still ok `endpoint-libs/libmyname-v1/myname/myname-v1-generated-source/`
but next one is `com/google/api/services/my.package.name/myname/` and `com/google/api/services/my.package.name/myname/model/`.

Despite it every single `.java` file of generated libraries has in my opinion wrong package:

```
    package com.google.api.services.my.package.name.myname.model;
```

If anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can see the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199903/498860), or follow this [bug entry](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=117) for status of a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Google just posted GPE 3.2.3 and a server side fix which appears to correct the issue; however, existing code is not necessarily backward compatible. As an example, changes are required in the standard Google generated GCMIntentService:

1. Migrated to usage of the new com.google.api.services path, as:

   import com.google.api.services.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
   import com.google.api.services.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
   import com.google.api.services.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;
2. Modified the call to insert methods from:

   endpoint.insertDeviceInfo(new com.google.api.services.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo().setDeviceRegistrationID(registration)).execute();

   to:

   endpoint.deviceInfoEndpoint().insertDeviceInfo(new com.google.api.services.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo().setDeviceRegistrationID(registration)).execute();

I have been unable to find the official documentation on why this breakage was required and rationale.