# Project 'CloudTasks' is missing required source folder: 'CloudTasks/endpoint-libs/libdeviceinfoendpoint...'

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Thank you in advance for your help.  I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/) and I'm getting 3 errors message "missing required source folder." I've searched and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185123/appengine-connected-android-project-dead-on-arrival) that talk about the mismatched path and how to change the path.  I've tried to change the path and it did not work.  Can you help me with steps of what I can do to correct this problem?  Please see the attached picture of the error.

Thank you,

Tim

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the project->properties->Java Build Path
Select Source tab, click on add folder, select CloudTasks/endpoint-libs/deviceinfoendpoint/deviceinfoendpoint-v1-generated-source

do the same for any other missing folder, basically this folder contains the generated source, and it should be configured as a source folder in order to compile the project.

after this just clean the project, it should work.